# How to replace Mojolicious sessions with a custom implementation?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

By default Mojolicious sessions create a signed cookie for the session. 
I would like to override this behavior. I can extend Mojolicious::Sessions and override the load and store methods, but how do I use my class instead of the default Mojolicious::Sessions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [documented](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious#sessions), the Mojolicious::Sessions object is held in the app's [`sessions` property](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious.pm#L36). Therefore you can either override it on creation

```
my $app = MyApp->new( sessions => MySessions->new );
```

or afterward

```
$app->sessions( MySessions->new );
```